# Помогите решить задачу на python с помощью BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautiful-soup, openstreetmap

Задача с курса. Не могу понять как ее решить.

В OpenStreetMap XML встречаются теги node, которые соответствуют некоторым точкам на карте. Ноды могут не только обозначать какой-то точечный объект, но и входить в состав way (некоторой линии, возможно замкнутой) и не иметь собственных тегов. Для доступного по ссылке https://online.hse.ru/pluginfile.php/1013134/question/questiontext/2225363/1/4513151/task_8_3_1_map2.osm фрагмента карты посчитайте, сколько всего тегов node не содержат в себе ни одного тега tag (первое число в ответе), а сколько содержит хотя бы один тег tag (второе число в ответе). Числа введите через пробел.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Не понимаю как именно посчитать количество тегов node в которых содержится хотя-бы один тэг tag, я понимаю только как посчитать вообщем количество тэгов tag в тегах node.

Comment: приведенная вами ссылка доступна только зарегистрированным пользователям

Comment: начнем с того. что по вашей ссылке никого не пустят, кроме студентов (может еще преподавателей) вышки :)